# деление строки на символы для дальнейшей работы с определённым символом

Tags: python

Итак, мне нужно разбить строку, (допустим, строка будет "123" символы: "1", "2", "3") чтобы в дальнейшем использовать определённый символ из строки (допустим, для сравнивания:

```
a = random.randint(1,3)
if a == *элемент из строки*:
   ...
```

или для записи в список.
помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Скорее всего, разбивать не надо, т.к. строка является последовательностью символов (sequence), и к нужному можно обращаться по индексу s[i]

Comment: простите, вижу, что ваш вариант мне пригодится, но "s" это функция, для обращения по индексу(порядковому номеру в строке)?

Comment: s - это пример идентификатора строки.   Может быть, стоит что-то почитать? Это самые базовые вещи

Answer (score 0):

```
text=input()  # вводимый текст
i=len(text)  # узнаем длину
s = []
for number in range(i):  # записываем посимвольно в список
    s.append(text[number])
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача связана именно со случайным выбором символа из строки, то можете использовать `random.choice`:

```
import random

string = '123'
ch = random.choice(string)
if ch == '2':
    ...
```